# Azure active directory and owin authentication

Tags: azure, owin, azure-active-directory, katana

Just faced an strange issue with azure ad applicationS and owin openid authentication.
To reproduce the issue.

1.create a web app with azure ad authentication in vs 2015 choosing cloud app template .

2.let the standard code be as is.

3.let startup.auth as is.

4.Run the app on local it works fine.

5.now change code in startup àuth as follows

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

    public static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

    // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
    string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

    private static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        logger.Debug("SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType called");
        //app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(
        new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnResponseSignIn = ctx =>
                {
                    //logger.Debug("OnResponseSignIn called");
                    ////ctx.Identity = TransformClaims(ctx.Identity);
                    //logger.Debug("TransformClaims called");
                }
            }
        });

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                   AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                   {
                       var code = context.Code;
                       ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                       string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                       logger.Debug("OnResponseSignIn called");
                       logger.Debug("signedInUserID =" + signedInUserID);
                       TransformClaims(context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity);
                       logger.Debug("TransformClaims called");
                       AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                       AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                       code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);



                       return Task.FromResult(0);
                   },



                    // we use this notification for injecting our custom logic
                    SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                    {
                        logger.Debug("SecurityTokenReceived called");
                        //TransformClaims();  //pass the identity
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },


                }
            });
    }


    private static void TransformClaims(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        if (identity != null && identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            var usserobjectid = identity.FindFirst(ConfigHelpers.Azure_ObjectIdClaimType).Value;
                ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)identity).AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("DBID", "999"));
                ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)identity).AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Super","True"));
        }

        // return identity;
    }

}
```

6.Run the app on local it will work perfect.

7.Deploy the app on azure websites and the startup àuth owin notification methods will never be called.however app works but identity transformation not

Can somebody help out what's wrong with this is azure ad apps doesn't support cookies or notification not firing or anything wrong with code.

Just to re-assert else than startup.àuth no standard code is changed.

Comment: Try removing the logger.Debug("OnResponseSignIn called"); lines and deploy again. sometime trace.writes could cause a problem while hosting in Azure depending on what is your trace listener...

Comment: i added logger.debug("OnResponseSignin Called") to keep log of all events firing or not , and if this could have been issue , it could have not functioned on localhost too perfectly , and so to find out only what is going on i added log4net logger and still it runs perfect on localhost and not on azure website. so i am  sure , this is not the issue . you can reproduce it , i had pastd the complete code .

Comment: That will work on local, but in azure it wont... try doing  remote debugging to see what's wrong...

Comment: Done that all ready and after all tries ,finally posted to see what could be wrong . logger is not an issue , igñore it. Issue is no notification is fired and henceforth no transformation of identify takes place.

Comment: Any body from Microsoft azure ad team or azure ad expert to take ahead from here and lead to solution.....?????

Comment: The only thing that prevents notifications from firing is if the authentication process doesn't get that far (e.g. something went wrong early on). Yet you claim the login works fine? One of these should be false. Try hooking up all of the notifications to see how far the process gets. You can also prove the notifications fire by doing something more dramatic like throwing a custom exception.

Comment: Can you give a try to above code with ur azure ad tenant creating a application ,and suggest the working solution ...  Login doesn't fails..that's sure...

Comment: Please try Tratcher 's suggestion and let us know how that goes.

Comment: Hi rich, I had done that hope u had read the thread in totality,I am saying it works perfect on localhost with notifications firing and when deployed the login works perfect but no notification fires .you can try the code urself. Let's chat n reach a solution if possible.

Comment: Tratcher , on hooking all the events , still it remains same , all of them fires and executes successfully on localhost and none of them executes on azure , still asserting there is no login failure , the ad authenticates and user logs in .

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a bit old, but I had exactly the same issue recently and spent hours trying to understand why it wouldn't work in Azure but it worked absolutely fine in my localhost.

This is basically a configuration issue: in portal.azure.com select your app and then go to settings > authentication / authorisation and make sure that app service authentication is OFF.

It turns out that this setting will take over your startup.auth settings.

I have to give full credit to Vittorio Bertocci as pointed that out to me.